# How to deal with a secrecy agreement when looking for other jobs.

Tags: interviewing, quitting, first-job, secrecy, government

My current position is at a government department, and is subject to a secrecy agreement.

I'm looking for a new job. I'm wondering how I deal with what's appropriate to talk about in job interviews, in terms what technology I've worked with, what my responsibilities were etc.

I work as a data analyst/software developer. In any job interview, I want to be able to tell the interviewer, 'this is what the software looked like, this is how I made my contribution etc'. But I don't want to break the secrecy agreement.

How would I best find out what's appropriate to talk about, and what's off limits?

I could discuss it with one of the well respected seniors in my current position, but this does put me in the awkward position of tipping my hand that I'm looking for new work.

Comment: This is likely covered in one of these questions: [1](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15323/), [2](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11740). I highly recommend [this answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/11743/7945) (note: it's mine).

Answer (score 0):

There is likely documentation stating what you are not allowed to disclose with outside sources. Take a look at the agreements you signed, they may explicitly prohibit discussion of certain material.

Are you in contact with anyone else who you used to work with and left? They probably went through a similar experience in needing to apply for new jobs and making sure they don't say anything they're not allowed to in the process.

When speaking about your skill set and experiences, speak in general terms. Avoid giving the name of where you used of learned something. For example instead of saying "while working for XYZ we used AutoCAD to draft our blue prints" say "I have experience drafting with products such as AutoCAD".